# Using Field Calculator to append attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have a field containing the file names for photos. I need to add the folder location to the beginning of each file name. Anyone know the code for doing this in Field Calculator?

Comment: Are all of your photos in the same location, or do you need to be able to programmatically add folder location info from a number of different locations?

Comment: They are all in the same folder location. It should be simple, I just can't remember the correct codeing for the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And...if you want to use VB, you simply add an " & " between your folder location and your existing photo ID: "Your folder location" & [Existing ID]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using the Python parser, you can combine text using `+`.  For example:

```
"C:/this/is/a/test/" + !FileName!
```